# Wireless adapter not working after updates TP LINK Archer T4U

Tags: drivers, wireless

I've got TP-Link Archer T4U and Ubuntu 16.04

In order to make it work, I installed [community drivers from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NY9j.png)

The installation proccess was like this:

```
# sudo cp -R . /usr/src/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-1.0
# sudo dkms add -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
# sudo dkms build -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
# sudo dkms install -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
```

Then came some updates from Update manager, probably kernel update and the driver stopped working.

The additional drivers applet shows:

[image]

I tried to reinstall it, but it says that the module is already loaded.

I'm quite new to Ubuntu. Please, help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to properly uninstall the driver from github. And you need to disable SecureBoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Pilot6, he gave a good advice.

So, I fixed it.

Disabled the secure boot. Then run the command

```
sudo dkms remove -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0 --all
```

And then

```
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux -v 1.0
```

After reboot, my wi-fi works again. And now I know how to deal with it after future kernel updates.
Thanks

Comment: You do not need to re-install after kernel upgrades. DKMS will handle it. SecureBoot was the problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 Not true. Today I've got another kernel update and this happened again even with SecureBoot "disabled". But remove/install module helped.

Comment: This means that you broke something in your DKMS system. This happens. You need to clean `var/lib/dkms` directory and re-install modules.

Comment: @Pilot6 How do you disable SecureBoot?  I don't have an option for it in my bios.  And how do you clean /var/lib/dkms and re-install modules.  Just delete the directory or is there some commands?